# Best Practice to handle large data in HDBSCAN cluserting using tfidf

Tags: python, clustering, bigdata, map-reduce

I am now about to implement `HDBSCAN` on a very large set of data, a few million sentences, using tfidf. However, as we know `HDBSCAN` clustering is computationally expensive and it's intuitive to apply vertical scaling to make it work.

But I am looking into resources or any implementation/ best practices to handle large data in `HDBSCAN` so that I can apply horizontal scaling, i.e faster algorithmically developed approaches.

I came across [Mapreduce implementation of HDBSCAN](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8674542) but haven't found a good resource explaining them or any implementation.

Do you happen to know any other methodologies?

Comment: A trick to be aware of is hierarchical clustering on K-means. Huge speed increase, lower accuracy if your going after purely HDBSCAN.

Comment: A lot of production systems I've worked on use language models to build embeddings for the sentences, then apply clustering on that - rather than TF-IDF.

Comment: yes aware of language models, I want to just use tfidf as of now with hdbscan on large data.